# Property undefined errors are not shown in console using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a project that I didn't start myself initially. For some reason undefined errors are not being logged in the console.

If for example I start a new project on Stackblitz (https://angular-ivy-zgxetk.stackblitz.io) and define an object then try to access a property on the undefined object it reports an error in the console for that object like:

> ERROR
> Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myProperty')

Which makes it clear where to fix it but in my current project it partially renders the UI and then nothing happens due to the undefined error. The error is not visible in the console logging though which sometimes requires a lot of time to find out what the problem actually is.

I tried copying the tsconfig from the Stackblitz project but it did not solve this issue. Any ideas why I don't see undefined errors in the console?

The current tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "dom",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a filter in the console or have you removed erroes from being printed? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hhfh.png

Comment: do you have an ErrorHandler defined in the app module?

Comment: @Mr.Stash thanks to your comment I found the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @Mr. Stash I found the issue was an ErrorHandler. I was using ApplicationinsightsAngularpluginErrorService in the app module.

```
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: ApplicationinsightsAngularpluginErrorService
    },
```

It turned out that because of this the messages with null errors or undefined were not logged anymore to console (found in this [article](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/configuring-azure-application-insights-in-an-angular-application#sending-errors-to-application-insights)).

The solution turns out to be adding new ErrorHandler in the extensionConfig

```
    private appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
        instrumentationKey: this.appConfig.insights.instrumentationKey,
        extensions: [this.angularPlugin],
        extensionConfig: {
            [this.angularPlugin.identifier]: {
                router: this.router,
                errorServices: [new ErrorHandler()],
            },
        },
    },
});
```